# Showing jupyter notebook files in latex

Tags: python

I'm currently working on my thesis.
And I've written some python code in Jupyter notebook files and I would like to show these files
in latex.

How can I do this best?

Regards

Comment: What have you discovered on the Jupyter site about exporting a notebook as LaTeX? Have you explored any packages in LaTeX that allow you to typeset code?

Comment: I've already experienced with listings, this works but it doesn't has like the different "color" to seperate functions and classes and so on.

Comment: Not sure if I get your question. Maybe you are looking for something like the `listings` package. Overleaf has a good overview article about the topic: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/code_listing.

Comment: Thank you sir. Very much